# Python decode() doesn't work - but only under windows

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.x, decode

OK... it's really simple. I have a (very simple) script that gets data from a url, and then decodes it (I will use it later if it will work).

```
rsp=urllib.request.urlopen(myurl)
print(rsp.read().decode("cp1255"))
```

When I'm executing this, I'm getting

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode 
 return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position
```

This is happening though, only on Windows!!!

I have a Linux machine (Ubuntu 12.10, love it) same IDE (eclipse) same python version (3.2.3) same script and it works nicely. I get all the text, it's readable and processable.
I have checked the directory - cp1255 is present. I have tried to replace "cp1255" with "cp1252" - it works, but the encoded text is gibberish.

Am I missing something here? I got the same settings in both projects, but it is currently only working on Linux.

Comment: How to reproduce? I guess that your data differs on different OSes...verify this first yourself. My trust in your claim is close to zero.

Comment: The problem is with the print line. If I only decode, it's works fine. So yes, this is probably an OS issue

Comment: Any 1255 page will do. E.g http://www.nrg.co.il/

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, the problem is not with `decode()` at all. The issue you have is with `encode()`. Python cannot send unicode directly to your terminal, it has to be encoded using whatever encoding your terminal claims to support.

If you are running on Windows then you are probably running in a command window. Check what codepage you are using by typing `chcp` at the command prompt; on my system that shows I'm using codepage 850 but I think from the error your command prompt is cp1252. The text you are trying to print must contain a character that cannot be encoded using your command prompt's codepage.

If the `print` is simply for debugging then you can try:

```
print(repr(rsp.read().decode("cp1255")))
```

and see if that helps.

Alternatively before you run the script use `chcp 1255` to set your command prompt to the same codepage as your data, or `chcp 65001` to set your command prompt to use utf-8. Don't forget to also check that the font you are using supports Hebrew characters.

Comment: I'm using eclipse console window and not the command line, unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work there or I'm missing something.

However, when using the Python shell, everything works just fine, So it seems to be a Windows command line issue. There's nothing to it - I'll output that to a file anyway, so the actual goal is achieved, but for now, the question is still not answered

Comment: What does `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` say?

Comment: it says Cp1252 on the eclipse console

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. cp1252 doesn't include the Hebrew characters so you would need to change the codepage that eclipse is using for the console.